# long long to byte array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c

I am sending a long long to a byte array with other stuff to a java server. When I convert the long back at the java end its not what I am expecting. I have tested the java converter but I ObjectiveC I thought that with it been low level would be as simple as this.

```
uint8_t *data = alloca(sizeof(longlong));
memcpy(&data[sizeof(Byte)+1],&theLong,sizeof(long long));
```

Is that right or am I on the wrong tracks?

Comment: can be helpful probably: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362384/are-integers-in-java-little-endian-or-big-endian

Comment: Rather than do the alloca, I'd just take the `&` of the long long and cast that to a byte pointer, to access the bytes.  No need for heap allocation/disposal.  Or do the regular shift/mask to get at the bytes.

Comment: I had only done that so that long long could go in to a payload array with other things. But even if I did that wouldn't I still have the same problem

Comment: Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe... Depend on the endianess... take a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness