# write a function that determines whether a computer is big endian or little endian in java

Tags: java, endianness

I've reed this code which is in C format but i didn't understand what's the process exactly. can anyone explain it for me in java or if there is a better way in java could you please write it here? thank you

```
bool endianess(){
 int testNum;
 char *ptr;

 testNum=1;
 ptr=(char*) &testNum;
 return (*ptr); //* return the byte at the lowest address
}
```

Comment: That's a difficult question. The JVM is always big endian, so you'll need to invoke native code to determine the host machine endianess (if that's what you're asking).

Comment: Short answer: You can't, other than by querying system attributes or doing strange things with memory-mapped buffers.

Comment: so, what's the point of using character here?

Comment: @faranak777 Java is not C.

Comment: i know, i mean in the above code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a Little Endian architecture, the integer value 0x1 will be written out in memory like

```
0x1 0x0 0x0 ....
```

so that function will return 1

Conversely, in a Big Endian architecture, the order of bytes will be

```
0x0 0x0 ... 0x1
```

however many bytes are in an int (greater or equal to 2 for it to work), and so

this function will return 0.

Here's a reference for why it [can't be done in Java directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362384/are-integers-in-java-little-endian-or-big-endian), but you could use [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) to escape out to a C library and return the result.

Answer (score 1):

You may use System.getProperty("sun.cpu.endian").  Alternately, you may use SIGAR (https://github.com/hyperic/sigar), Java native access, JNI etc. to get this information.