# Read Array<Uint16Array> of char code from string in C

Tags: c, typed-arrays

I wrote JavaScript string as binary that converts each character of string to Uint16Array(2bytes) like this:

```
for(let i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    dv.setUint16(i * 2, name.charCodeAt(i));
}
```

I checked the file size and byte number was correct, but when I read a string from C, it prints unexpected numbers:

```
27904
28416
25600
25856
29184
28160
24832
29696
28416
29184
```

Read from JavaScript, it's like this, as I expected:

```
109
111
100
101
114
110
97
116
111
114
```

This is a code of C that reading a string from file:

```
// Read name
for(int i = 0; i < nameLen; i++) {
    short int c;
    fread(&c, 2, 1, fp);
    printf("%d\n", c);
}
```

And it's JavaScript code for reading string:

```
for(let i = 0; i < nameLen; i++) {
    let char = dv.getUint16(i * 2);    // Each of character has 2 bytes
    console.log(char);
}
```

Also when I tried with int, it saids:

```
117468416
117468928
117466112
117466368
117469696
117468672
117465344
117470208
117468928
117469696
```

As I know, short int is 2 byte length, so theoritically looks like it's fine, but why am I got those big numbers?

I tried this on my computer,

```
printf("%d\n", sizeof(short int));
```

And it saids 2.

I'm not good at C, so actually it's quite hard to find out what is the problem.

Any advice will very appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: 27904 is hex 0x6d00, and the decimal version of 0x6d is 109.

Comment: Java experts, don't crucify me for asking this: Aren't java multi-byte scalars [big-endian](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362384/are-integers-in-java-little-endian-or-big-endian)? that seems to be where this is heading. You have a BE-short being loaded into something that uses LE.

Comment: @WhozCraig You meant JavaScript, right?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: "As I know, short int is 2 byte length" - That's not guaranteed. Don't rely on it, use correct marshalling with bitshifts & bitops. There are enough Q&A here, do some research.

Comment: When debugging binary data always use at least hex representation. You would have seen that f.ex. the first number expected is 0x6D, what you get is 0x6d00, ie. a byte-order problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for comments. I resolved with shifting 8 bits to right, because DataView of JavaScript writes binary as little-endian as default.

```
char name[100] = "";

for(int i = 0; i < nameLen; i++) {
    short int c;
    fread(&c, 2, 1, fp);
    c >>= 8;
}
```